# Remove row where date is between two dates

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to delete the rows from dataframe df1, if the **current dat**e is between the **ShiftScheduledStart** and **ShiftScheduledEnd** values. My idea was the code below, however this does not give the right result.

```
df1[(df1['ShiftScheduledEnd'] < CurrentDateVar) & (CurrentDateVar < df1['ShiftScheduledStart'])]
```

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anand, yes indeed I want and but if I replace & with and it returns:

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @AnandSKumar No, you have to use bitwise `&` with arrays, I think the OP wants `df1[(df1['ShiftScheduledEnd'] > CurrentDateVar) & (CurrentDateVar < df1['ShiftScheduledStart'])]` the logic is incorrect in the original

Comment: Can you post data, it's possible that your condition is never satisfied

Comment: The bitwise & works, however the logic does not result in the right dates? It should remove the rows where the CurrentDateVar does not fall between the ShiftScheduledStart and ShiftScheduledEnd. 

The line @EdChum does not result, in the right rows? No rows are deleted.

Comment: ShiftScheduledEnd ShiftScheduledStart
16-5-2015 14:30 16-5-2015 6:00
13-7-2015 22:00 13-7-2015 14:00
13-7-2015 22:30 13-7-2015 14:00
13-7-2015 22:00 13-7-2015 14:00

CurrentDateVar 14-7-2015 23:45

Comment: Please edit your question, the formatting is lost in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're expecting but none of your rows satisfy your condition:

```
In [7]:

t="""ShiftScheduledEnd,ShiftScheduledStart
16-5-2015 14:30,16-5-2015 6:00
13-7-2015 22:00,13-7-2015 14:00
13-7-2015 22:30,13-7-2015 14:00
13-7-2015 22:00,13-7-2015 14:00"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0,1])
print(df1)
CurrentDateVar  = pd.to_datetime('14-7-2015 23:45')
CurrentDateVar
    ShiftScheduledEnd ShiftScheduledStart
0 2015-05-16 14:30:00 2015-05-16 06:00:00
1 2015-07-13 22:00:00 2015-07-13 14:00:00
2 2015-07-13 22:30:00 2015-07-13 14:00:00
3 2015-07-13 22:00:00 2015-07-13 14:00:00
Out[7]:
Timestamp('2015-07-14 23:45:00')
In [8]:

df1[(df1['ShiftScheduledStart'] < CurrentDateVar) & (df1['ShiftScheduledEnd'] > CurrentDateVar)]
Out[8]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ShiftScheduledEnd, ShiftScheduledStart]
Index: []
```